# Why does <motion.div> throw an "invalid hook call" error in framer-motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to implement a toggle animation in the framer-motion react library. In the navbar component, a `motion.div` element should render (open) when the `<HiMenuAlt4>` icon is clicked and not render (close) when the `<HiX>` icon is clicked. Instead, clicking the icon throws an invalid hook error on click. (But it works if I change <motion.div> to <div).

Minified code:

```
import {HiMenuAlt4, HiX} from "react-icons/hi";
import {motion} from "framer-motion";
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function NavBar() {
    const[toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    return ( 
        <div className="header">
           
            <div className="app__navbar-menu">

            <HiMenuAlt4 onClick={()=>{ setToggle(true); } }/>
                        
                        {/* The troublesome line of code: */}
                        
                        {toggle && (
                        <motion.div
                            whileInView={{x:[300, 0]}}
                         transition={{duration: 0.85, ease: "easeOut"}}
                            >

                             <HiX onClick={() => {setToggle(false)} }/>

                             <ul>
                {['Home', 'About', 'Work', 'Skills', 'Contact'].map(
                    (item) =>  (<li key={item} >
                        <a href={`#${item}`} onClick={() => setToggle(false)}>{item}</a>
                        </li>) 
                        )}
            </ul>

                         </motion.div>)}
               

            
            
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}

export default NavBar;
```

What I've tried previously:
1.) I stumbled on an online source that suggests the motion.div implements the React Hooks library, and placing motion.div in a conditional statement breaks the rules of hooks, hence the error (if I understood the post correctly). But I'm following a tutorial and it works perfectly in their own code. Github code: https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_professional_portfolio/blob/master/src/components/Navbar/Navbar.jsx

2.) The framer-motion docs also has limited information on conditional animation.

Comment: Any chance you have something like a CodeSandbox going where you're able to reproduce the issue? I set one up here - https://codesandbox.io/s/72178336-framer-motion-div-msnc1y?file=/src/NavBar.tsx - using the code that you posted and it _seems_ to be working (though probably not looking as you expect it to as I didn't apply any styling).

Comment: @brianmarco, Thanks a lot for your help. Turned out to be a configuration error. When I compared your files with mine, I realized that framer-motion was not written in my package.json (probably because I installed the library before doing create-react-app). Re-installing the library cleared the hook error. I feel so silly now. Thanks for your help.